# Checkbox watched elements not updating Checkbox UI in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have some checkbox elements like this:

```
<label>Item 1 <input type="checkbox" v-model="items" value="Item 1" /></label>
<label>Item 2 <input type="checkbox" v-model="items" value="Item 2" /></label>
<label>Item 3 <input type="checkbox" v-model="items" value="Item 3" /></label>
```

I added a watcher to prevent them from selecting more than 2 elements:

```
watch: {
  items() {
    if(this.items.length > 2) {
      alert('You can only pick 2 items');
      this.items.splice(-1,1);
      console.log(this.items);
    }
  }
}
```

The items inside of view updates correctly (if they select item 1, item 2, and then item 3 it removes item 3 from the array).

The alert box also pops up.

However the checkbox doesn't uncheck in the html and I can't figure out why it's not unchecking since it's bound to the v-model.

I tried `this.items.pop()` as well with the same effect.

Comment: Did you declare the `items` array upfront in the data section?

Comment: Yes they were declared upfront